# "bad variable name" using "read var"

Tags: bash, variables, ubuntu, server

I am getting confused about Linux shells. It may be that I oversee something obvious as a Linux noob.

All I want is the following script to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type some Text:"
read var
echo "You entered: "$var
```

Here is the situation:

- Installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 in a VirtualBox on windows
- Installed it with this [packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4hqH.png)
- A SAMBA mounted on /media/buff
- The script is on /media/buff/ShellScript/test.sh
- made executable by "sudo chmod a+x /media/buff/ShellScript/test.sh"
- The rest is default
- I am using PSPad on windows to edit the script file

I [read](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) about the dash but I'm not getting it.
Here are some variations:

Using sh to launch

```
user@Ubuntu:/media/buff/ShellScript$ sh test.sh
Type some Text:
:bad variable nameread var
You entered:
```

Using bash to launch:

```
user@Ubuntu:/media/buff/ShellScript$ bash test.sh
Type some Text:
': Ist kein gültiger Bezeichner.var (means no valid identifyier)
You entered:
```

Changed the Shebang in the script to "#!/bin/sh", Using sh to launch

```
user@Ubuntu:/media/buff/ShellScript$ sh test.sh
Type some Text:
:bad variable nameread var
You entered:
```

I searched across the Internet for hours now and I assume, that the script itself is ok, but there are missing some environment settings.
I used "sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash" to set dash as default shell (which I think is ubuntu default anyway)

sadface panda :)

Comment: BTW, if you read the bash tag wiki, this would be **the very first thing** it says to check **before you ask a question**. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about those info pages. The error messages did not help on finding informations about the problem on google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are most probably carriage returns (CR, `'\r'`) at the end of your lines in the shell script, so the variable is trying to be read into `var\r` instead of `var`. This is why your error message is meaningless. A similar error should [look like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506415/why-i-obtain-this-error-when-i-try-to-perform-this-simple-bash-script):

```
run.sh: 3: export: [... the variable name]: bad variable name
```

In your case bash throws an error because `var\r` is illegal for a variable name due to the carriage return, so it prints

```
test.sh: 3: read: var\r: bad variable name
```

but the `\r` jumps to the beginning of the line, overwriting the start of the error message.

Remove the carriage returns fom the ends of lines, possibly by using the `dos2unix` utility.

Comment: **Notepad++** does the job: `Edit` > `EOL Conversion` > `Unix (LF)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a [list of editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors#Newline_support) that support unix newline character.

Brackets has an [extension](https://github.com/LonelyStorm/brackets-newline) for new-line/end-of-line support and it is built-in in Notepad++. Go to the 'Edit' tab. Find 'EOL Conversions' and select Unix (LF).
That should get it done.